# Empty string if null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my code:

```
SelectList(blah, "blah", "blah", cu.Customer.CustomerID.ToString())
```

It gives a error when it returns null, how can I make it CustomerID is an empty string if it is null?

/M

Comment: Is `CustomerID` the null value, or is the `Customer` itself null? Also, what is the type of `CustomerID`?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**(Update for C# 6.0)**

If you are using C# 6 or newer (Visual Studio 2015 or newer), then you can achieve this using the [null-conditional operator `?.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
var customerId = cu.Customer?.CustomerId.ToString() ?? "";
```

One useful property of the null-conditional operator is that it can also be "chained" if you want to test if several nested properties are null:

```
// ensure (a != null) && (b != null) && (c != null) before invoking
// a.b.c.CustomerId, otherwise return "" (short circuited at first encountered null)
var customerId = a?.b?.c?.CustomerId.ToString() ?? "";
```

For **C# versions prior to 6.0** (VS2013 or older), you could coalesce it like this:

```
string customerId = cu.Customer != null ? cu.Customer.CustomerID.ToString() : "";
```

Simply check if the object is non-null before you try to access its members, and return an empty string otherwise.

Apart from that, there are situations where [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern is useful. That would mean that you ensure that your `Customer`'s parent class (type of `cu` in this case) **always** return an actual instance of an object, even if it is "Empty". Check this link for an example, if you think it may apply to your problem: [How do I create a Null Object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178399/how-do-i-create-a-null-object-in-c).

Answer (score 29):

(C# 2.0 - C# 5.0)

The ternary operator works, but if you want even shorter expression working on arbitrary objects you can use:

```
(myObject ?? "").ToString()
```

Here is real-life example from my code:

```
 private HtmlTableCell CreateTableCell(object cellContents)
 {
     return new HtmlTableCell()
     {
         InnerText = (cellContents ?? "").ToString()             
     };
 }
```

Comment: One of the outcomes of this code is redundant `"".ToString()`, moreover `(myObject ?? "")` will work only if `myObject` was a string in the first place, making `.ToString()` even more unnecessary. I think you meant `myObject?.ToString() ?? ""`.

Comment: @ensisNoctis 1. This was written at the time we had C# 5, which didn't have `?.` operator. For C# 6+, I'd use `?.`. 2. `.ToString()` works on objects just fine.

I stand by my answer scoped to C# 2 - C# 5: updated to clarify.

Comment: Fine with me :)

Answer (score 17):

It depends of the type of `CustomerID`.

If `CustomerID` is a string then you can use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
SelectList(blah, "blah", "blah", cu.Customer.CustomerID ?? string.Empty)
```

If `CustomerID` is a [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), then you can use:

```
SelectList(blah, "blah", "blah", cu.Customer.CustomerID.ToString())
```

This will work because the [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx) method of `Nullable<T>` returns an empty string if the instance is `null` (technically if the [HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) property is `false`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SelectList(blah, "blah", "blah", 
(cu.Customer.CustomerID!=null?cu.Customer.CustomerID.ToString():"")
)
```