# How to set empty string when null values are passed

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, so I am new to C Sharp and I have one function call which might send null values. I want to make sure that if its null then I should **set those null as empty string**. Below is what I have tried and it works but I think there must be an elegant way to achieve this.

```
public static Concat ()
{ 
        // imagine x = null and y = null
        Abc( x, y);
}

public static Abc ( string x , string y)
{
       // blah blah
        x = x ?? "";
        y = y ?? "";
        efg( x, y);
}
```

I looked into this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660269/empty-string-if-null) but I could  not understand it. Can I do something in the `Abc arguments/parameter` itself. I mean

```
public static Abc ( string x Can I do something here , string y Can I do something here)
    {
           // blah blah
            x = x ?? "";
            y = y ?? "";
            efg( x, y);
    }
```

Comment: No you cannot, as defined.  If you allow passing a `string` (and `null` is a valid value for a string), then null can be passed as the parameter value. Your example snippet will do the trick though: `x = x ?? "";` can be read as "set x = x if x is not null, but if it's null, set it to blank string.

Comment: Or you can avoid 2 extra lines by simply having "efg (x ?? "", y ?? "");"

Comment: C# does not have support for non-nullable reference types. Suppose it hadm, then your method might have looked like `public static Abc(string! x, string! y)` where the exclamation marks would mean that the compiler guarantees these are never null. For some related suggestions for future C# features, see for example [Proposal: Nullable reference types and nullability checking](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5032).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think there must be an elegant way to achieve this.

There is: the `??` operator. You found it.  Good on you.

> `Abc ( string x Can I do something here`

You can say

```
public static Abc(string x = "", string y = "")
```

and now you can call it

```
Abc("a", "b);
Abc("a"); // actually calls Abc("a", "")
Abc();    // actually calls Abc("", "")
```

but this does not change the behaviour when null is passed in.  It allows you to omit an argument, not change the value of a null argument.

Comment: Actually the original project that I am working on had the same thing `public static Abc(string x = "", string y = "")` in it. But because of null vaues I was getting issues in my DB.  Can you tell me one thing. If I keep `public static Abc(string x = "", string y = "")`. Does this make the x and y as optional parameter. I mean I can simply call `Abc()` and it would still work right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no compile time check supported natively by C# to enforce non-null values on reference types, including `string`.

You may provide a default value e.g. `void DoSomething(string x = "")`, however this does not prevent someone from overriding it with a null value.

Comment: Since `string.Empty` is not a `const`, it is not a compile-time constant and cannot be used for a default value. You can define your own `const` and use that, or you can go with the literal `""`, that is `void DoSomething(string x = "")`.

Comment: My bad ! Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Minor improvement:

```
public static Abc ( string x , string y) => efg(x ?? "", y ?? "");
```

Not much different from you have already. The `?` operator (as in `someObject?.SomeProperty`) returns the value of `SomeProperty` if `someObject` is not `null`. This does not apply in your example.